# How does headers keep sync in both client and server side in HTTP/2?

Tags: http2

As `HTTP/2` use [hpack](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541) to compress headers, it has a static table and a dynamic table per connection. But I got a question, how does client & server side sync headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tables: one for the client-initiated messages and one for server-initiated messages.

As per the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541#section-2.2):

> When used for bidirectional communication, such as in HTTP, the
> encoding and decoding dynamic tables maintained by an endpoint are
> completely independent, i.e., the request and response dynamic tables
> are separate.

Both client and server must manage copies of both tables. So when a client sends a message it updates it’s copy of the client table, and when the client receives a message, the client updates it’s copy of the server table. And similarly on the server side.

As TCP guarantees the delivery order of messages it’s possible to keep the client table in sync on the client and server side (and similarly with the server table side). This would be more complicated on a connection where in-order messaging is not guaranteed so QUIC uses a variety on HPACK called [QPACK](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-qpack) which has extra features to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

For an HTTP2 connection to initiate, a TCP connection should have already been established. Then, the client prepares and sends the first HTTP2 packet containing a SETTINGS frame prefixed with the magic string and creates two separate dynamic tables for this particular TCP connection, one for client-orignated messages and another for server-originated messages. When the server side receives an HTTP2 packet prefixed with the magic string, it similarly creates its two separate dynamic tables.

When the client prepares the first HTTP2 request, it first constructs the HEADERS frame and appends all the needed headers inside it. Each header of the first HEADERS frame is either a 1 byte length index of the static table (e.g. 0x02 -> method: GET) or a literal representation of the header consisting of several bytes. In the latter case, the first byte of the byte sequence is to provide information to the server on how to handle and store this new header. Meanwhile, the client has already stored the header in its dynamic table.

When the server side receives the first HTTP2 HEADERS frame, it decodes the header block using its static table to decode the one-byte headers. For each literal header, it creates a new entry in the dynamic table based on the information it retrieved from the first byte of this header bytes sequence.

The second time a frame containing headers (HEDERS, CONTINUATION or PUSH PROMISE) is prepared from the client side, each used header which is already stored in the dynamic table is represented as 1 byte* (dynamic table index). For each header that is used for first time and does not exist in the static table, literal representation is used  again and a new entry is added in the client dynamic table. When the server side receives the second frame, it looks at its static or dynamic table to decode the one-byte headers.  For each literal header (appeared for first time) it also creates a new entry in its dynamic table.

This way the dynamic tables for client-originated messages remain synchronized in both sides. In a similar way remain synchronized  the dynamic tables of server-originated messages.

The same process continues until the termination of the TCP connection. Gradually, the dynamic tables are filled and less literal representations are needed.

It is obvious that the in-order delivery of frames is critical. This is secured from the underlying TCP protocol. Also, the headers should always be processed in a serial way in both sides.

HTTP2 uses [HPACK](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7541.html) format for header compression.

**For the sake of simplicity 'Literal Header Fields with Incremental Indexing and New Names' have been assumed in the above example*.